# Как посмотреть запросы которые делает RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring

Как посмотреть запросы которые делает RestTemplate, и есть ли такая возможность, никак не пойму как работают его методы, какой итоговый URI генерируется, можно конечно тупо самому генерить и отдавать ему готовый, но хочется сделать красиво, в документации только общее описание никакой конкретики

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вашу проблему, решение находится здесь. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-resttemplate-logging

Так же можно попытаться самому разобраться пользуясь исходным кодом.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.java